# Cloning browser data to another computer

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari

I have 5 different browsers on the same computer. Is cloning the passwords/usernames and other data as easy as copying over the information under App Data for Windows?

Edit: As mentioned below, are there any security issues I might run in to?

Comment: Search the site with terms like "copy <browser_name> profile".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with firefox, after you get to /username/AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/ there is a random user string it creates something.default that I believe is unique to the install. So therefore, I believe the short answer is: no this will not work.

you maybe able to trick firefox to using this profile with some registry work, but you're out of my scope at this point.